# RecursionError while trying to change background on multiple windows in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

Last night I started a mini project where I wanted to make a game using `tkinter` (as opposed to `pygame` mainly because I don't know how to make multiple windows in `pygame`).

I want the user to guess the RGB values and compute their accuracy. Yet, whenever I run my code I get a `RecursionError` during the `startgame` function and none of the colors change. I'm confused as to why.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class multiWindow(Tk):
def __init__(self):

    # ******* CREATE WINDOWS *******

    window1 = Tk()
    window2 = Tk()
    window3 = Tk()

    # ******* WINDOW DIMENSIONS *******

    windowH = 100
    windowW = 250

    # ******* SCREEN RES *******

    screenW = 1366-windowW
    screenH = 768-windowH

    # ******* COORDINATES OF WINDOWS *******
    window1.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (windowW,windowH,screenW/6,screenH/3))
    window2.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (windowW,windowH,screenW/2,screenH/3))
    window3.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (windowW,windowH,screenW/(6/5),screenH/3))

    # ******* WINDOW TITLES *******
    window1.title("Color1")
    window2.title("Color2")
    window3.title("Color3")

    # ******** BUTTON START *******
    buttonStart = Button(window1,text="Start Game", command=lambda: self.startGame())
    buttonStart.pack()


    # ******* OPEN WINDOWS ******* 
    window1.mainloop()
    window2.mainloop()
    window3.mainloop()




# ******** PRODUCE RANDOM COLOR ********
def randomRGB(self):
    return random.randint(0,255)


def guessRed(self,window):
    while True:
        try:
            print("I want you to guess the RGB values of the colors in the windows above.")
            print("Guess the red value of the window displaying ",window)
            guess = int(input())

            if guess < 0 or guess > 255:
                raise
            else:
                return guess
                break
        except:
            print("Error")

def startGame(self):
    # ******** DETERMINE COLOR VALUES *******
    colorVal = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

    for x in range(0,len(colorVal)):
        colorVal[x] = self.randomRGB()

    # ******* GIVE WINDOWS COLOR *******
    self.window1.configure(background='#%02x%02x%02x'%(colorVal[0],colorVal[1],colorVal[2],))
    self.window2.configure(background='#%02x%02x%02x'%(colorVal[3],colorVal[4],colorVal[5],))
    self.window3.configure(background='#%02x%02x%02x'%(colorVal[6],colorVal[7],colorVal[8],))

multiWindow = multiWindow()
print("This comes after multiwindow class")
```

I'm not very well adversed in `tkinter`. Just started reading about it 2 days ago, but I feel this problem has less to do with my grasp of `tkinter` than my grasp of python.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `multiWindow = multiWindow()` Don't use a variable with the same name as a class.  This may not have anything to do with your specific problem, but it's certainly _a_ problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your program must have exactly one instance of `Tk`, and you must call `mainloop` exactly once. If you need additional windows, create instances of `Toplevel`. Nothing will work the way you expect if you have more than one instance of `Tk`.

You also need to remove your infinite loop in `guessRed` as well as the call to `input`. A GUI shouldn't be getting input from the console.

---

Unrelated to any other problems, you don't need to use `lambda` in the following:

```
Button(window1,text="Start Game", command=lambda: self.startGame())
```

In this case the `lambda` serves no purpose other than to make the code slightly more complex. Instead, just pass a reference to the function:

```
Button(window1,text="Start Game", command=self.startGame)
```